# Ayuda con recorrer json en c# mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio, mvc

Amigos recurro a ustedes nuevamente. Lo que quiero saber es como puedo recorrer este json:

```
{"codigo_postal":"84100","municipio":"Nogales","estado":"Sonora","colonias":["Aguajito de la Morita","Felizardo Amador","Hector Soto","Jorge Leal","La Morita (El Aguajito)","Casildo Santa María","Ruben Martínez Fimbres","El Choclo","El Tapiral","Los Cuervos","Rubén Darío Rodríguez","La Arizona (La Hacienda)","Los Castro","Rafael Carrizosa","San Miguelito","Rubén Barnet","Elena Rodríguez","Jiráhui","José Ignacio Real","Luis Santa María","Agua Caliente","Casas Blancas","La Angostura","La Pasadita","Doña Chepa","El Aguajito","El Tascali","La Ciénega","Las Borregas de Abajo"]}
```

Cual es la idea que los datos de colonias los ponga en un combobox.

Este es el codigo que he realizado pero no se como recorrer las colonias.

```
$('#BtnValidarCodPostal').on('click', function () {
    var CodigoPostal = $('#CodPostal').val();
    $("#ValidandoCodigo").show();
    if (CodigoPostal != "" || CodigoPostal != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: _urlBase + "CodigoPostal/GetCodigoPostal",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { Codigo: CodigoPostal },               
            success: function (emp) {
                $.each(emp, function (i, item) {
                    console.log(item.Colonia);
                });

                $("#ValidandoCodigo").hide();
                $("#ResulCodPostal").show();
                $('#Estado').val(emp.codpos.Estado);
                $('#Delegacion').val(emp.codpos.Municipio);

                //console.log(emp);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
               // bindForm();
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Y este es el action result:

```
public JsonResult GetCodigoPostal(string Codigo)
{
    List<MtoCodigoPostal> CodigoPostal = db.MtoCodigoPostales.Where(o => o.CodigoPostal == Codigo).ToList();
    return Json( new {codpos = CodigoPostal.Take(1).ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // return Json(new { clave = Result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Agradecería el apoyo prestado.

---

Con este codigo, pero aun asi no funciona:

```
$.each(data, function (index) {
    var colo = data[index].Colonia;
    var colonias = data.Colonia;

    console.log(colo);

    $('#Estado').val(data[index].Estado);

    $.each(colo, function (_index) {
        colo[index].Colonia;
    })

    $.each(colonias, function (index, value) {
        console.log(index + ':' + value);
    });                           
})
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba el siguiente código. Es acceder a la propiedad `colonias` del resultado de la llamada `ajax`

```js
var emp = {
 codigo_postal: "84100",
 municipio: "Nogales",
 estado: "Sonora",
 colonias: ["Aguajito de la Morita",
 "Felizardo Amador",
 "Hector Soto",
 "Jorge Leal",
 "La Morita (El Aguajito)",
 "Casildo Santa María",
 "Ruben Martínez Fimbres",
 "El Choclo",
 "El Tapiral",
 "Los Cuervos",
 "Rubén Darío Rodríguez",
 "La Arizona (La Hacienda)",
 "Los Castro",
 "Rafael Carrizosa",
 "San Miguelito",
 "Rubén Barnet",
 "Elena Rodríguez",
 "Jiráhui",
 "José Ignacio Real",
 "Luis Santa María",
 "Agua Caliente",
 "Casas Blancas",
 "La Angostura",
 "La Pasadita",
 "Doña Chepa",
 "El Aguajito",
 "El Tascali",
 "La Ciénega",
 "Las Borregas de Abajo"]
};

$.each(emp.colonias, function(index, value) { 
    console.log(index + ':' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: que tal amigo puse tu código como indicas sin embargo le manda el mensaje TypeError: obj is undefined; sigo intentando

Comment: Hola. El código es un ejemplo. La parte interesante es el `$. each() `. Adaptalo

Comment: ok deja intentar

Comment: que tal amigo ya intente solucionar y de verdad no he podido intente haciendo lo siguiente

Comment: que tal amigo ya intente con los each pero de verdad no he podido solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Tenemos la variable obj que contiene el objeto en cuestión. Para recorrer la propiedad de colonias podemos usar la estructura for que ofrece javaScript que es homologa a la función each que estás usando. Este for requiere crear una variable que en nuestro caso es "o" la cual contendrá en cada iteración el valor de colonias por lo que con console.log(o) estamos imprimiendo cada valor de colonias. Para tu caso puedes hacer lo que requieras dentro de ese for, que tu caso entiendo que puedes crear una nueva estructura para llenar tu combo.

```
var obj = {"codigo_postal":"84100","municipio":"Nogales","estado":"Sonora","colonias":["Aguajito de la Morita","Felizardo Amador","Hector Soto","Jorge Leal","La Morita (El Aguajito)","Casildo Santa María","Ruben Martínez Fimbres","El Choclo","El Tapiral","Los Cuervos","Rubén Darío Rodríguez","La Arizona (La Hacienda)","Los Castro","Rafael Carrizosa","San Miguelito","Rubén Barnet","Elena Rodríguez","Jiráhui","José Ignacio Real","Luis Santa María","Agua Caliente","Casas Blancas","La Angostura","La Pasadita","Doña Chepa","El Aguajito","El Tascali","La Ciénega","Las Borregas de Abajo"]}

for(var o of obj.colonias){
    console.log(o)
}
```

Para crear una nueva estructura puedes intentar algo como esto

```
var listCombo = [];
//Este for cambia un poco debido a de esta manera podemos acceder a los indices de cada elemento del array de colonias
for(var[i, o] of obj.colonias.entries()){
    listCombo.push({key: i, value: o})
}
//Esto da como salida
[
{key:0, value: "Aguajito de la Morita"},
{key:1, value: "Felizardo Amador"},
{key:2, value: "Hector Soto"},
.
.
.

]
```

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué tu propuesta soluciona el problema.

Comment: Hola Brayan, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código, sin una explicación del mismo, no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle y lee [answer] para más información. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es por la forma en la que accedes a la propiedad de tu objeto, por lo que veo creas un objeto anonimo con la propiedad `codpost` el cual es una coleccion por lo que en tu ciclo en `javascript` necesitas acceder primero a `codpost` el cual es una lista por lo que debera ser tratado como tal.

Ejemplo:

```
$.each(emp.codpos, function (i, item) {
   $('#Estado').val(item.estado);
   $('#Delegacion').val(item.municipio);
    console.log(item.colonias);
    //aqui tu ciclo que rrecorre las colonias
 });
```

otra opcion si siempre obtendras un objeto con una coleccion de colonias pudes usar

```
new {codpos = CodigoPostal.FirstOrDefault()}
```

De esta manera solo utilizas solo el ciclo para recorrer las colonias

```
$('#Estado').val(emp.codpos.estado);
$.each(emp.codpos.colonias, function (i, item) {
});
```